# How to integrate ECharts with BIRT/Pentaho?

Tags: charts, reporting, reportviewer, pentaho, birt

I'm looking for a report engine which may:

- connect to data source via JDBC
- create logic data set by grouping/aggregating the raw data
- include a data filter on the top of each report, which allows my client use the report interactively
- add custom charts, in my case, it's ECharts https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts
- **support multi-tenancy paradigm (new requirement)**

Now BIRT and Pentaho are the two players on my table.

For pentaho, it's really hard to find useful document to at least clarify if it's capable. Please if you're familiar with it, let me know **if pentaho community version meets my requirements**.

For BIRT, I've found evidence it support my first 3 needs. But for custom charts, I can only find examples/docs about adding custom IMAGE/SVG charts. As ECharts is based on canvas, I'm not sure **if it's possible to integrate ECharts with BIRT**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to integrate javascript charts in BIRT. Basically:

- Select the top-level element of your report outline -> Script tab -> clientScripts
- Include here your echart resources (.js and .css) using "head.js" (see link below for more informations)
- Add a text element to the report
- Set the type of this new element to 'HTML'
- In a script tag, initialize your echart object in a "head.ready()" instruction (see link below for more informations). The tricky part is to understand how to use a server-side dataset in a client-side chart within this html script.

You can find more informations and a full example of a such report [here](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/922-using-jvectormaps-and-jquery-with-birt/), this example embeds a [jvectormap](http://jvectormap.com/) in a birt report. Furthermore, see [a live demo here](http://www.visioneo.org/geographical-tree), where a [JIT chart](http://philogb.github.io/jit/index.html) is integrated in a BIRT report.

However since these charts are created using a client-side framework, obviously BIRT won't be able to export them in PDF format. You can see in the live demo linked above, how a BIRT report can easily handle a different output when users export to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Pentaho, but which tool to use it's a matter of debate.

Using Pentaho Report Designer:
- Connects to DBs using JDBC;
- Allows grouping rows based on a field or fields and calculating functions such as running sums;
- Can use selectors (single or multi-valued selectors) to interact with the report, passing the selector values to the queries;
- As far as I can tell, you don't have many options to choose a specific charting engine.

However, you can use CCC as the charting engine, which is a Protovis based Javascript charting engine, cross-browser compatible (for the most part), renders SVG charts with a decent fallback for IE (I believe the fallback is flash but I'm not sure if it changed recently) and produces decent looking charts.

If you HAVE to use that chart library, then I suggest using C-Tools dashboards instead, where you can embed as many different JS files you want and you have full control over the JS and CSS of the page. But most of the reporting functions from PRD will have to be implmented by you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe the enterprise edition meets all my requirements, but in this project, I have to choose the community version.

Comment: All tools suggested here are Community Edition too. Pentaho Report Designer can be downloaded here: http://community.pentaho.com/projects/reporting/; The report rendering plugin is part of the Pentaho core in both CE and EE editions. As for C-tools, the C stands for Community.

Comment: Thanks @nsousa, btw, do you have any FREE document/tutorial about C-tools?

Comment: try the webdetails website, they're the project owners. But documentation is not very complete.